# Will any 3'5 inch hard drive caddy / enclosure be OK to operate a SSHD?

Tags: external-hard-drive

Since there are no external SSHD's on the market, I will make my own. Obviously the size is 3'5 inches - but is there anything else to bear in mind before putting one in the enclosure.

Obviously it will slower than Sata - maybe someone can point me to a link which shows the difference in boot up times between internal and external SSD performance.

But I have heard that just because an enclosure fits - it does not guarantee it will work with the SSHD within it.

Something like this:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-3-0-3-5-Inch-SATA-HDD-Hard-Disk-Drive-External-Case-Enclosure-Caddy-Black-/380668750190?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item58a1a0296e

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to a Solid State Drive or Solid State Hybrid drive?
Any external enclosure you wish to make yourself will suffice assuming you have the connections needed to allow it to communicate back to the computer. 
When you buy an external pre-made enclosure, it would come with a controller board that offers one of the following connection types listed below. You can technically run a standard sata cable to the hard drive directly but you would need an external power supply. Fry's Electronics sells them. You could also look on newegg or amazon.
Typical external connections types are going to be either eSata, USB, or Firewire based.
Out of those, the fastest is eSata. This does assume however that you have an eSata port on the the computer to connect to. If not, Firewire 800 or USB3.0

As far as the enclosure goes, adding some type of active fan would help with any heat coming off of the hard drive itself. It depends on what you'll be using it for but, just a suggestion.

As an example, something like this would work:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA24G28N3521

Comment: wow, most enclosures look fanless, and I would assume they would be Ok, because they exist on the market for a long time. That looks big compared to i.e - a passport external hdd.

Comment: also it says usb 3.0 can handle more gbps than esata ?

Comment: USB3.0 is rated for 5GB and eSata is rated for 3GB. Anything over 2GB should work great. I typically see data transfers around 150mb/s over a USB3.0 flash drive. In my experience, eSata has held a more consistent connection but honestly, you can use either one. Don't believe the tech specs every time though. Just because it says it can go 3GB doesn't mean it will in real world applications. It's just a number given by the Manufacturers to give a ceiling of what it could be pushed to under optimum lab settings. Look for reviews and comparison shop a little before making any final decisions.

Comment: I would recommend an open enclosure like this one ==> http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182307R&cm_re=open_usb3_hdd_enclosure-_-17-182-307R-_-Product And yes, the USB3 specs are faster than eSata, but in reality eSata is faster. I have done extensive measurements. See here ==> https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&resid=475a0a48ca6d4035%211965&app=WordPdf